# Magento2: How can I override core js module price-box.js

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I need to extend `Magento_Catalog/js/price-box.js`. I have used the 'mixins' feature, but it's not working for `price-box.js`.

`requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box': {
                'My_Module/js/price-box/pluggin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`My_Module/view/frontend/web/js/price-box/pluggin.js`

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) { 
        // modify target
        var reloadPrice = target.reloadPrice;
        target.reloadPrice = function() {
           cosole.log("hello");
        };
        return target;
    };
});
```

Comment: Yogesh, Give some more information about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Specify PriceBox js file in your custom module's `requirejs-config.js` with the same name by which its already declared in core modules. in our case it is **`priceBox`** like below. Your modules **`requirejs-config.js`** would be something like

   ```
   var config = {
       map: {
            '*': {
                   priceBox:'namespace_modulename/js/custompricebox',
            }
       }
   };
   ```
2. Now, create the file **`custompricebox.js`** to the path specified above. i am assuming you want to extend **`reloadPrice`** method in price-box. so your **`custompricebox.js`** would be like below.

   ```
   define(
       [
           'jquery',
           'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
           'underscore',
           'mage/template',
           'mage/priceBox',
           'jquery/ui'
       ],
       function ($, utils, _, mageTemplate) {

           'use strict';

           $.widget('yournamespace.custompriceBox', $.mage.priceBox, {
               /**
                * Render price unit block.
                */
               reloadPrice: function reDrawPrices() {

                   var priceFormat = (this.options.priceConfig && this.options.priceConfig.priceFormat) || {},
                       priceTemplate = mageTemplate(this.options.priceTemplate);

                   _.each(this.cache.displayPrices, function (price, priceCode) {
                       price.final = _.reduce(price.adjustments, function(memo, amount) {
                           return memo + amount;
                       }, price.amount);

                       // you can put your custom code here. 

                       price.formatted = utils.formatPrice(price.final, priceFormat);

                       $('[data-price-type="' + priceCode + '"]', this.element).html(priceTemplate({data: price}));
                   }, this);
               },


           });

           return $.yournamespace.custompriceBox;
       }
   );
   ```
3. Please note this code is not tested. there might be some syntex errors. let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: Hi Yagnesh, Can we achieve it via Mixin ? Instead of override it, can we extend it too ?

Comment: @PrafulRajput, I don't use mixin yet, i will surely update you on this once i do it.

Comment: somehow this does not work for me (ver. 2.1.2). Also mage/priceBox does give me some script error.

Comment: Did someone succeeded to rewrite it through Mixin ?

Comment: any update on this?