# Magento 2: How to override core js module price-bundle.js

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides, magento-2.0, requirejs

I am attempting to override the `_onQtyFieldChanged` event in the `mage.priceBundle` widget in the `module-bundle/view/base/web/js/price-bundle.js` file.

I am referencing the Magento dev docs (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html) and this Magento StackExchange question ([Magento2: How can I override core js module price-box.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/magento2-how-can-i-override-core-js-module-price-box-js?rq=1)), but I can't manage to get my custom `_onQtyFieldChanged` event method to execute. As of now I only have a `console.log` statement in that method.

A little background: 
My custom `price-bundle.js` file is found in `Endertech/BundleExtended/view/base/web/js` directory. 
My `requirejs-config.js` is in `Endertech/BundleExtended/view/frontend`.

`requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            priceBundle: 'Endertech_BundleExtended/js/price-bundle',
            'Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle': 'Endertech_BundleExtended/js/price-bundle'
        }
    }

};
```

`Endertech/BundleExtended/view/base/web/js/price-bundle.js`:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'priceUtils',
    'priceBox',
    'priceBundle',
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, utils) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('Endertech.priceBundle', $.mage.priceBundle, {

        _onQtyFieldChanged: function onQtyFieldChanged(event) {
            console.log("Endertech Module"); 
            var field = $(event.target),
                optionInstance,
                optionConfig;

            if (field.data('optionId') && field.data('optionValueId')) {
                optionInstance = field.data('option');
                optionConfig = this.options.optionConfig
                    .options[field.data('optionId')]
                    .selections[field.data('optionValueId')];
                optionConfig.qty = field.val();

                optionInstance.trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });

    return $.Endertech.priceBundle;

});
```

EDIT:

So I realized that probably the issue I am coming across is the fact that the widget method I am trying to modify is a private method in `module-bundle/view/base/web/js/price-bundle.js`. Which is the reason why I can't override it or extend it. I am not sure if there is a way to get around this or a different approach I need to take to this issue that I don't know about.

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: We may have architecture for this. Checking.

Comment: Confirmed, we have JavaScript mixins which can do this. You'll get a response soon.

Comment: @benmarks thank you so much for looking into my issue, I had also thought about JavaScript mixins, but the first time I attempted it I was having issues accessing some of the `$.mage.priceBundle` parameters and methods.

Comment: @NoemiQuezada Please mark the correct answer

Comment: Hi @NoemiQuezada have you got solution for it. please share the piece of code if you find any solution regrading it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue like you and found a workaround, but don't know if it is helpful. I am going to share it anyway.

I resigned to override the function. Then I was trying to override the whole widget, but couldn't get it to work either. The widget wasn't overridden and the magento standard widget was loaded.

I inspected the generated  `pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<location>/requirejs-config.js` file. It seems to me, that the modules' requirejs configurations are inserted in a alphabetical order. Thus, the `priceBundle` variable of my module was overridden by the one of the magento-bundle module, because my vendor starts with a 'C'.

For testing purposes I created a new module and changed the vendor to 'XC...'. After that the overriding of the whole widget works.

But I am still interested in how to override just one function.

Comment: I tried this adding a Z in front of Endertech for the vendor name and now for the first time my `price-bundle.js` file gets loaded. Thank you! Like you though, I would like to understand how I can just override one method. However, after testing the solution I realized that another method has to be modified slightly because when you update a product that is in the cart the product summary is not updated correctly.

Comment: I'm glad that the workaround is working for you, too. Now, I'm wondering about the quantity of the radios when you update a product that is in the cart. It seams to me, that the quantity is being set to the default instead of to the user configured one. I did not changed anything about radios and can reproduce this behavior in other online demo shops. I already opened an issue at github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4942. Thus, don't waste your time, if you experience the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should intrude in requrejs sequence be adding dependencies for your extension, config will be:

```
var config = {

             map: {
                    "*": {
                          priceBundle: 'SOURCE_TO_EXTENDED_PRICE_BUNDLE'
                         },
                         'Endertech_BundleExtended/js/price-bundle': {'priceBundle': 'SOURCE_TO_ORIGINAL_PRICE_BUNDLE'}
                         }

            };
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but my file did not load at all.

Answer (score 1):

What I also found that worked was the following

In the module requirejs-config:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'mage/SwatchRenderer': 'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer',
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': 'MyVendor_MyModule/js/swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};
```

And then I created a mymodule/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js that contained:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/SwatchRenderer',
], function ($) {
    $.widget('myvendor.SwatchRenderer', $.mage.SwatchRenderer, {
        _Rewind: function (controls) {
            controls.find('div[option-id], option[option-id]').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
            controls.find('div[option-empty], option[option-empty]').attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
            console.log('test');
        },
    });

    return $.myvendor.SwatchRenderer;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your core js use widget then you also call that widget and return that widget variable in a mixin.

Bundle mixin you have to create `requirejs-config.js` in your custom module at 
`Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`   put below code in appropriate js

`requirejs-config.js` :

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle': {
                'Vendor_Extension/js/price-bundle-mixin': true
            }
        }
    },
};
```

`price-bundle-mixin` :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'priceUtils',
    'priceBox'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, utils) {
    'use strict';

    return function (priceBundle) {

        $.widget('mage.priceBundle', priceBundle, {
            // function which you want to overwrite
        });

        // don't forget to add a function which is used by your  
        // functions, else it will show undefined function error

        return $.mage.priceBundle;
    };
});
```