# Magento 2 - Overriding a built in magento widget - configurable products dropdown

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to make some changes to the configurable product dropdowns in the front end product display on Magento 2.1.0.  I want to do this through re-writing the configurable javascript widget.

I created a `requirejs-config.js` in `app/code/myMod/blah/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`.  It looks like this:

```
var config = {
  map: {
    '*': {
      configurable: 'myMod_blah/js/configurable'
    }
  }
};
```

I have my new copy (with just one line added so I can recognize it) of the `configurable.js` file here:
`app/code/myMod/blah/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js`

When I look at the contents of the `requirejs-config.js` file on the page I can see my config very close to the top, but then near the bottom is still the old config that looks like:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

And, when I look at the contents of the `configurable.js` file in the source of the loaded page, sure enough, it's the magento default version, not mine (it doesn't have the line I added).

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit: I believe my question is directly related to this previous question, which has a workaround, but not an actual answer: [Magento 2: How to override core js module price-bundle.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118153/magento-2-how-to-override-core-js-module-price-bundle-js?rq=1)*

Edit #2 - this work around works, when I preface my company/mod directories with zzmyMod and zzBlah, the correct js file shows up, because, as I guessed, it is added to requirejs-config.js AFTER all the magento stuff instead of before and therefore gets processed after magentos own definition for "configurable."  I'd still really like to know how to fix this because I don't like naming my module this way.

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: Have you applied below solution or not ?

Comment: Please, update your question with the code lines of this file also: `app/code/myMod/blah/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js`

Comment: Yes, I ran your suggested commands.  No change.  I'm pretty sure it has no hope of working correctly if there is are two competing definition on the requirejs-config.js file.  Since Magento's default definition appears later in the file, it is the last one processed.  How do I prevent theirs from overriding mine?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Update it?  I added my own line of code to it before I ftp'ed it into place.  Do you want me to change it again?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh The configurable.js file is quite long.  But, it is exactly the same as magento's original js file, except I added a comment to it so that I could tell it's using mine when I look at the source of what comes out in the browser.

Comment: Ok! I will check your issue tomorrow or at the weekend.

Comment: did you get any solution, can you please post your answer @Todd

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy static content to see your changes.

Run bellow command for deploy static content

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Now you can check your changes.

Comment: I have my magento software in development mode - it was my impression that there is no need to clean caches when using this mode.  In any case, I have run the commands you suggested, and cleared my browsers cache.  It still is using the old version of the configurable.js file.

Comment: check you file in this path pub\static\frontend\YourTheme\Package\en_US\Magento_Authorizenet\js

Comment: cache must be need to clean when if it enable from admin. please also clean cahce

Comment: I've cleaned the cache exactly as you asked, in the order you said to do it.

Comment: Have you checked file in above file ?

Comment: That is not a valid path, I am merely using the blank magento theme.  I can do pub/static/frontend/blank/en_US/Magento_Authorizenet/js/view/payment/ and there are some js files there.  None of them are named like any of the files I have mentioned in my post, and really, I don't think that the authorize.net module should come into play here, right?

Comment: sorry it is my mistake for the path you have to check it on you module path in pub\static\frontend\YourTheme\Package\en_US\myMod_blah\js