# JS event on configurable product frontend

Tags: configurable-product, javascript, magento-2.1, swatches

I am working on the configurable product view page.

I want to add an event to check if all options are checked before an AJAX call.

I tried a solution like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/magento2-how-can-i-override-core-js-module-price-box-js) to override the widget Magento_Swatches/js/SwatchRenderer, but failed. When I clicked or I chose an option, it didn't execute my custom function.

Do you have some advise for my problem and how should i do it?

Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, this is my soluytion.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/jquery.parsequery',
    'swatchRenderer'
], function( $, _ ){
    'use strict';

    $.widget( "mage.SwatchRenderer", $.mage.SwatchRenderer, {
        _init: function () {
            console.log( "custom init" );
            return this._super( );
        },
        _OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {
            console.log( "Custome click" );
            return this._super( $this, $widget );
        }
    });

    return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;

});
```

Comment: I tried the same code but it is not working for me. Can you please help me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182627/how-to-call-function-on-configurable-product/182629?noredirect=1#comment251134_182629