# How to call function on configurable product?

Tags: magento2

I have a dropdown on product detail page.

```
<div class="swatch-attribute no_of_window" attribute-code="no_of_window" attribute-id="165" option-selected="230">  
<span class="swatch-attribute-label">No of Window</span>  
<span class="swatch-attribute-selected-option"></span>
<div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
  <select class="swatch-select no_of_window">
    <option value="0" option-id="0">Choose an Option...</option>
    <option value="227" option-id="227">1</option>
    <option value="228" option-id="228">2</option>
 </select>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried,

```
require(['jquery'],function($){

$(document).ready(function(){

   $( "select.no_of_window" ).change(function() {
      alert( "Handler for  called change." );
    });
});

});
```

Event is not getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
       jQuery( "select.no_of_window" ).change(function() {
             alert( "Handler for  called change." );
       });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: what you getting on console log? , in your code semi colomn missing after `})`

Comment: I added semi colon still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
   $("select.no_of_window").on("change",function() {
         alert( "Handler for  called change." );
   });
});
```

if its not work try the second one

```
    <script>
   require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
       $(document).on("change","select.no_of_window",function() {
             alert( "Handler for  called change." );
       });
 });
</script>
```