# Is it okay to modify validation.js directly?

Tags: magento2, javascript

Is it okay to modify `lib/web/mage/validation.js` directly? If not, how do I override it? There's a bug there I want to fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No don't edit that file directly as it is a core file, you can overwrite it by adding it to your theme here:

```
app/design/frontend/STORE/THEME/web/mage/validation.js
```

Or alternatively you can use Require JS to change the file called as [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/magento2-how-can-i-override-core-js-module-price-box-js) explains